# UI not waiting for value before rendering

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm attempting to develop a Flutter Android app that will communicate with a Cloud Firestore database. I want it to go through each document in a series of references, get a value from each of these documents, increment a counter from the value that was read, and return it as a Text Widget. Problem is, the value that is read appears to not be reflected in the UI, although I can print out the counter correctly from the values read from the cloud.

I've tried utilizing StreamBuilder and FutureBuilder. My last attempt was by making my function return a Future, and awaiting for the value to be read, to no avail. All that is reflected on the UI is "Instance of Future".

```
Future<double> calculatePrice(DocumentSnapshot pedido) async{

    priceWrapper wrapper = priceWrapper(0);

    for (DocumentReference d in pedido.data['requested_products']) {
      d.get().then( (f) {
        wrapper.value += f['value'];
        print(wrapper.value);
      });
    }
    print(wrapper.value);
    return wrapper.value;
  }

 Widget buildListItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {
    return ListTile(
      //...
      trailing: Text("${calculatePrice(document)}",
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle,
      ),
    );
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: CustomDrawer(
        context: context,
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Requests"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        //...
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection("currentRequests").snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                print("SNAPSHOT ERROR: ${snapshot.error}");
              }
              return LinearProgressIndicator();
            }
            return ListView.separated(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return buildListItem(context, snapshot.data.documents[index]);
              },
            );
          },

        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The "print(wrapper.value)" call prints the expected value, but that does not show up in the UI.

Comment: You will need a FutureBuilder as a widget of your trailing property

Comment: use async request to force UI

Comment: Yes, my problem really was due to an incorrect usage of FutureBuilder. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a FutureBuilder that will render your `ListTile` only when the `calculatePrice` method is complete.

In the following example, the `ListTile` contains a temporary "..." when the calculation is in progress, and the actual result when the calculation is complete.

```
Future<double> calculatePrice(DocumentSnapshot pedido) async {
    priceWrapper wrapper = priceWrapper(0);

    for (DocumentReference d in pedido.data['requested_products']) {
      var f = await d.get();
      wrapper.value += f['value'];
    }
    return wrapper.value;
  }

 Widget buildListItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {
    Future<double> getPrice = calculatePrice(document);

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getPrice,
      builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return ListTile(
            //...
            trailing: Text("${snapshot.data}",
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle,
          );
        }
        else {
          return ListTile(
            //...
            trailing: Text("...",
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle,
          );
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Now, on the subject of why your code seems to work but doesn't, everything is located in this piece of code

```
    for (DocumentReference d in pedido.data['requested_products']) {
      d.get().then( (f) {
        wrapper.value += f['value'];
        print(wrapper.value);
      });
    }
    print(wrapper.value);
```

The `get` method is an async one and does not interrupt the execution flow. Insteand it will register a callback (in the `then`) that will be called when the `get` is complete. As the execution flow is not interrupted, the `for` loop will iterate on all data. Then, the last `print` statement will be executed.
Later, the callback are going to be called.

As the code is not interrupted, your `calculatePrice` method will effectively compleyte very fast, but with a result of `priceWrapper(0)` (the initial value of `wrapper`). That is the value that will be used to create your `ListTile` and why it doesn't seem to work.

Using the `FutureBuilder` allow you to manage the rendering of your application when all the async work is done.

Answer (score -1):

Put an await in your calculatePrice function.

```
for (DocumentReference d in pedido.data['requested_products']) {
  await d.get().then( (f) {
    wrapper.value += f['value'];
    print(wrapper.value);
  });
}
```

Also what is being returned is a Future, not a double so

```
     Widget buildListItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {
         calculatePrice(document).get().then( (price) { 
             return ListTile(
              trailing: Text("$price"),
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle,
             )
          }
          ).catchError((error, stackTrace) {
            return Text("Error");
            });
     }
```

Hope this helps